# Why can't I do fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", a...)?

Tags: go

I'm learning Go and I'm stuck with Go tour (exercise-stringer.go: https://tour.golang.org/methods/7).

Here's some code:

```
type IPAddr [4]byte  
// TODO: Add a "String() string" method to IPAddr.
func (a IPAddr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", a...)
}
```

So I figured the inner representation of `IPAddr` is `[4]byte`, so spread operator works. But I'm getting:

```
cannot use []string literal (type []string) as type []interface {} in argument to fmt.Sprintf
```

What the heck? String slice doesn't work either, what's going on here?

**EDIT**: Sorry, there's an error in my question - error was about type `IPAddr`, not `[]string`. I was playing with the code and I've pasted wrong output.  Anyway, thanks to [peterSO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221700/peterso) and [0x434D53](https://stackoverflow.com/users/437276/0x434d53) about invariance of slices in Go.

Well, this raises another question. Why is it implemented in this way? I imagine you'd just have some `Iterable` interface, so any struct implementing it would "just work".

**Sidenote**: when I first heard about Go there was this bold statement "compiled, but expressive". And explicit interface implementation is great example of this, but things like explicit conversion, lack of operator overloading and so on give me "90s Java feel". Which is sad, because Go seems like a great language.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/)
>
> Exercise: Stringers
>
> Make the `IPAddr` type implement `fmt.Stringer` to print the address as a
>   dotted quad.
>
> For instance, `IPAddr{1, 2, 3, 4}` should print as `"1.2.3.4`".
>
> ```
> package main
>
> import "fmt"
>
> type IPAddr [4]byte
>
> // TODO: Add a "String() string" method to IPAddr.
>
> func main() {
>   addrs := map[string]IPAddr{
>       "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
>       "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
>   }
>   for n, a := range addrs {
>       fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", n, a)
>   }
> }
> ```

There is no implicit conversion of `[]string` to `[]interface {}`. See [Conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) in [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec). You need to provide an explicit conversion. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type IPAddr [4]byte

// A "String() string" method for IPAddr.
func (a IPAddr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3])
}

func main() {
    addrs := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for n, a := range addrs {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", n, a)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
loopback: 127.0.0.1
googleDNS: 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 10):

As stated in the Go FAQ section [Can I convert a []T to an []interface{}](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface), there is no implicit conversion from a typed array to an `[]interface{}`:

> It is disallowed by the language specification because the two types
> do not have the same representation in memory. It is necessary to copy
> the elements individually to the destination slice

The following solution works but require the creation of an intermediate slice:

```golang
func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    tmp := make([]interface{}, len(ip))
    for i, val := range ip {
        tmp[i] = val
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", tmp...)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the go language specification:

> If f is variadic with a final parameter p of type ...T, then within f the type of p is equivalent to type []T

But in Go slices and arrays are type invariant. So an `[]T` is different from `[]U` if `T` and `U` are different types. They are not related at all, even if `T` is an structural subtype of `U`. So `[]string` is not an `[]interface`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this method for the Stringer interface.

```
func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v.%v.%v.%v", ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3])
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

The `range` should be used to iterate over the array, so the answer would be like as follows:

```
func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    out := fmt.Sprintf("%v", ip[0])
    for _, value := range ip[1:] {
        out += fmt.Sprintf(".%v", value)
    }
    return out
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    var s []string;
    for _, v := range ip {
        s = append(s, fmt.Sprintf("%v", v))
    }
    return strings.Join(s, ".")
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, when I 'run':
package main

import "fmt"

```
type IPAddr [4]byte

// TODO: Add a "String() string" method to IPAddr.
func (a IPAddr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", a...)
}

func main() {
    addrs := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for n, a := range addrs {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", n, a)
    }
}
```

The error is:

> prog.go:9: cannot use a (type IPAddr) as type []interface {} in
>   argument to fmt.Sprintf

and not

> cannot use []string literal (type []string) as type []interface {} in
>   argument to fmt.Sprintf

So, I think something got out of synch while copying and pasting.

`type IPAddr [4]byte` does not define a string, so the error message in the question is misleading.

It's a `[4]byte`, a completely different type (from a Go language type perspective) from string. It isn't a `[]byte` either.

Nor does `type IPAddr [4]byte` satisfy an interface, for instance implement String(), that fmt.Sprintf could use, because IPAddr's String() method doesn't get compiled.

You might try to convert the `[4]byte` to a string, but that conversion, `string(a)` isn't legal. Worse, the four byte values would be treated as character codes, and not converted to a character representation of the 4 small integer values.  It is quite likely that some IPAddr byte values might be invalid UTF-8 which would be even more weird if a program tried to print it.

As explained in other answers,
`return fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3])`
returns a string value of IPAddr in the format you are aiming for.

Once `func (a IPAddr) String() string` is valid, it works; `IPAddr` implements the fmt.Stringer interface.

Then `%v` in
`fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", n, a)`
 can be replaced by `%s` in
`fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", n, a)`
because the fmt output methods have an implementation of String().

I prefer `%s` to `%v` because it signals that the program is not relying on a 'default Go value representation' (i.e. for that array `[127 0 0 1]`), and that the type implements String().