# How to transform [4]byte{1,2,3,4} to "1.2.3.4" in Golang?

Tags: go

Here is my code which was used to transfer a byte array to string
but it was failed:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

type IPAddr [4]byte

// TODO: Add a "String() string" method to IPAddr.

func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    s := [][]byte{ip[:]}
    //fmt.Println(s)
    sep := []byte(".")
    return string(bytes.Join(s, sep))
}

func main() {
    hosts := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for name, ip := range hosts {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", name, ip)
    }
}
```

The program does not generate a expected output as

```
loopback: 127.0.0.1
googleDNS: 8.8.8.8
```

How to transform [4]byte{1,2,3,4} to "1.2.3.4" in Golang?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418107/why-cant-i-do-fmt-sprintfd-d-d-d-a

Comment: I found the same question in stackoverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418107/why-cant-i-do-fmt-sprintfd-d-d-d-a


but If there are other ways to transfer directly

Comment: See https://golang.org/src/net/ip.go#L260

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to define your own type as there is already [net.IP](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IP) which implements [fmt.Stringer](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer).

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    ip := net.IP{127, 0, 0, 1}
    fmt.Println(ip)
}
```

`net.IP` is a byte slice, so you can also do:

```golang
b := []byte{127, 0, 0, 1}
ip := net.IP(b)
fmt.Println(ip)
```

Answer (score 5):

1- Use `net.IP`, like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "net"

func main() {
    hosts := map[string]net.IP{
        "loopback ": {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for name, ip := range hosts {
        fmt.Println(name, ":", ip)
    }
}
```

output:

```
loopback  : 127.0.0.1
googleDNS : 8.8.8.8
```

---

2- Use this:

```golang
func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    return strconv.Itoa(int(ip[0])) + "." +
        strconv.Itoa(int(ip[1])) + "." +
        strconv.Itoa(int(ip[2])) + "." +
        strconv.Itoa(int(ip[3]))
}
```

like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

type IPAddr [4]byte

func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    return strconv.Itoa(int(ip[0])) + "." +
        strconv.Itoa(int(ip[1])) + "." +
        strconv.Itoa(int(ip[2])) + "." +
        strconv.Itoa(int(ip[3]))
}

func main() {
    hosts := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback ": {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for name, ip := range hosts {
        fmt.Println(name, ":", ip)
    }
}
```

output:

```
loopback  : 127.0.0.1
googleDNS : 8.8.8.8
```

---

3- Use `strings.Trim(strings.Join(strings.Fields(fmt.Sprint(ip)), "."), "[]")`
like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

type IPAddr [4]byte

func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    return strings.Trim(strings.Join(strings.Fields(fmt.Sprint([4]byte(ip))), "."), "[]")
}

func main() {
    hosts := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback ": {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for name, ip := range hosts {
        fmt.Println(name, ":", ip)
    }
}
```

output:

```
loopback  : 127.0.0.1
googleDNS : 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type IPAddr [4]byte


func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v.%v.%v.%v", int(ip[0]), int(ip[1]), int(ip[2]), int(ip[3]))
}

func main() {
    hosts := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for name, ip := range hosts {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", name, ip)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional explanation to your code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Note that [`net.IP` is a `[]byte`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IP) which [implements `String() string`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IP.String) so you can simply do:

```
net.IP{127, 0, 0, 1}.String() // => "127.0.0.1"
```

This strategy is much faster than `fmt.Sprintf(...)` or `strings.Join(...)`:

```
// ip_string_test.go

var ip = net.IP{127, 0, 0, 1}

func Benchmark_net_IP_String(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    ip.String()
  }
}

func Benchmark_fmt_Sprintf(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3])
  }
}

func Benchmark_strings_Join(b *testing.B) {
  ss := make([]string, len(ip))
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    for i, x := range ip {
      ss[i] = strconv.FormatInt(int64(x), 10)
    }
    strings.Join(ss, ".")
  }
}
```

`$ go test -bench=. ./ip_string_test.go`

```
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
Benchmark_net_IP_String-8       50000000            30.8 ns/op
Benchmark_fmt_Sprintf-8         10000000           194 ns/op
Benchmark_strings_Join-8        20000000           113 ns/op
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  6.123s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type IPAddr struct {
    A byte
    B byte
    C byte
    D byte
}

func (p IPAddr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v.%v.%v.%v", p.A, p.B, p.C, p.D)
}

func main() {
    hosts := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for name, ip := range hosts {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", name, ip)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since it's ip address, we can do like this

```golang
func (ipaddr IPAddr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v %v %v %v", ipaddr[0], ipaddr[1], ipaddr[2], ipaddr[3])
}
```